# jQuery - Create hidden form element on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hidden-field

What is the simplest way to dynamically create a hidden *input* form field using jQuery?

Answer (score 683, accepted):

```
$('<input>').attr('type','hidden').appendTo('form');
```

To answer your second question:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Comment: Note that IE will choke if you attempt to change the input type after it's created. Use `$('<input type="hidden">').foo(...)` as a workaround.

Comment: Also, jQuery documentation suggests that since DOM manipulation is expensive, if you have multiple inputs to be added, add all of them once using something like $(this).append(hidden_element_array.join(''));

Comment: I just tried this method with jQuery 1.6.2 and recieved this error with Firefox 7.0.1:

    "uncaught exception: type property can't be changed"

It seems that you cant use the attr method to change the type property under these conditions. I'm now trying the method below...

Comment: Will this same approach work with the newer `.prop` function in the newer API release?

Comment: @SpaceBison `.prop` is not "the new `.attr`" as a lot of people seems to think. You should still use `.attr` to set attributes.

Comment: I had trouble with this approach when I tried to add valid HTML for the input field, as I was unable to add either a </input> or <input /> type of field. If anyone knows a solution, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 155):

```
$('#myformelement').append('<input type="hidden" name="myfieldname" value="myvalue" />');
```

Comment: Did someone test this answer on old IE?

Comment: Personally, I believe this is a much better approach than the accepted answer as it involves less DOM manipulation/function calls.

Comment: @PaulSkinner For the given case, yes you are correct, but it isn't always so. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2690367/1067465

Answer (score 45):

The same as David's, but without attr()

```
$('<input>', {
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'bar'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Comment: Is there a name for this way of populating a tag?

Comment: how to append the input only 1 time? if its exist it keep entering new value with same attribute

Comment: Very streamlined, I love it.

Answer (score 29):

if you want to add more attributes just do like:

```
$('<input>').attr('type','hidden').attr('name','foo[]').attr('value','bar').appendTo('form');
```

Or

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'foo[]',
    value: 'bar'
}).appendTo('form');
```

Comment: this is giving console error  `Unexpected identifier` .

Comment: Second code, seems the "id" need to be generated dynamically something like foo1, foo2 etc

Answer (score 8):

```
function addHidden(theForm, key, value) {
    // Create a hidden input element, and append it to the form:
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = key; //name-as-seen-at-the-server
    input.value = value;
    theForm.appendChild(input);
}

// Form reference:
var theForm = document.forms['detParameterForm'];

// Add data:
addHidden(theForm, 'key-one', 'value');
```

Comment: What is the `'name-as-seen-at-the-server'`?

Answer (score 2):

Working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BTNN5/)**

If your form is like

```
<form action="" method="get" id="hidden-element-test">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
    <br><br>   
    <button id="add-input">Add hidden input</button>
    <button id="add-textarea">Add hidden textarea</button>
```

You can add hidden input and textarea to form like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add-input").on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-element-test').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" value="192.168.1.201" />');
        alert('Hideen Input Added.');
    });

    $("#add-textarea").on('click', function(){
        $('#hidden-element-test').prepend('<textarea name="instructions" style="display:none;">this is a test textarea</textarea>');
        alert('Hideen Textarea Added.');
    });

});
```

Check working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTNN5/)** here