# correct syntax for pure javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have this code:

```
function render(str)
{
    var main = document.createElement('div');
    with(main.style)
    {
          //style stuff here
    }

    main.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    document.body.appendChild(main);

    setTimeout(function(){
        try{
            document.body.removeChild(main);
        }   catch(error){}
    },5000);
}
```

This render a message inside a div, an then hides after 5 secs.

How I can add a input text and image to this form? Since I'm not sure how I can do with pure JS.

Comment: Your code already shows how to do it, in the sense that adding an input is done the same way as adding a div (and you're already adding a div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

input

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "person";

document.body.appendChild(input);
```

image
 img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "logo.png";

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

See live example here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/sM2Vd/

I would suggest, however, learning and using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - it's a great library that makes things like this a breeze.

See this SOq for a similar thing - creating `input` (type hidden in this case) element with jQuery and compare to plain JavaScript:

- [Jquery - Create hidden form element on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408043/jquery-create-hidden-form-element-on-the-fly)

Comment: I can do with jQuery, but pure JS is my next step :)

Comment: the code works, but i need to put inside the div created before, any ideas?

Comment: Sure - just append to `main` instead of `document.body`, here's an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sM2Vd/2/

Comment: That works like a charm. I appreciate your time, keep rockin'!

Comment: I would suggest you please remove your comments about jQuery. The OP is obviously a jQuery programmer, he's asking how to do it without jQuery since he's never programmed without jQuery.

Comment: @slebetman Yes, but others who run into the same question I think will definitively benefit from knowing there is such a better alternative - removing the jQuery info would get rid of that benefit.

Comment: In which case a single sentence would suffice. Everything else below that has no relevance to the question and should be edited out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
with(main.style)
    {
          //style stuff here
    }
```

and doing several style manipulations,

write all the style assignments in one go

main.style.cssText='//css style string here