# Add Html helpers with Jquery (Razor)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I need to add an @Html.HiddenFor when a button is clicked

My jquery code is this:

```
function btnAdd() {

var x;
y = $("#drpDwnPRTPP");  

$("#budgetsList ul").html('<li>Primer elemento ' +
'@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ToList()['+ c +'].PRTPP_ID, new { @id="prtppID"'+ c +', @value="'+ y.val() +'" })' +
'</li>'
   ); 
}
```

But when i clicked this is what i get in my html :

Primer elemento @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ToList()[0].PRTPP_ID, new { @id="prtppID"0,   @value="1" })

instead an input element

any way to do this ? ? ...

Comment: You are adding server code on the client..

Comment: you will have to make the input manually.

Comment: yep after looking this, i get like o.O why i ask this ? haha

is the hunger man haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML helpers are server side, Jquery is happening on the client side, so you are going to need to add your hidden field on the client side. See: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408043/jquery-create-hidden-form-element-on-the-fly)

Comment: yep, i dont why i ask this,is the hunger that i have, doesnt let me think clearly haha