# Submitting a form (post, NOT ajax) with some additional parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to perform a non-ajax post by clicking the submit of a form. Before submiting I have to add some additional form parameters. Here is how I do this:

```
  $("#my_form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    data.push({"name": "extra data1", "value": "extra value 1"});
    var params = $.param(data);
    //what's next?
    //$.post($(this).attr("action"), data: params); // ajax request, I don't need an ajax request
  });
```

But how do I actually submit the form so it will send **not only** its parametes, but **the additional ones** I've added to it as well? Obviously, `$(this).submit();` won't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to see this SO question : [Jquery - Create hidden form element on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408043/jquery-create-hidden-form-element-on-the-fly)

In your case, I guess you can do somethig like this to add a hidden input:

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function (e) {

   $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'extra data1',
        value: 'extra value 1'
    }).appendTo($(this));  

});
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/XyLUV/

---

Or, you could do the same thing like this:

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function (e) {

   $('<input type="hidden" name="extra data1" value="extra value 1">')
   .appendTo($(this));

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/Kkq6F/1/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden inputs for this purpose. Add

```
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='param1' VALUE='data1' ID='param1'>
```

and this will be submitted to php.

You can change value of this fields from jQuery by

```
$('#param1').value = 'data12';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pulling the data out of the form and then manipulating the data structure you get, just add hidden input elements to the form before submitting it.