# How to add a hidden list of IDs to a form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, hidden-field

I've got a simple form in html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="title" name="title" size="30" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Save this stuff">
</form>
```

I also have a file upload on the page, which handles uploads using ajax and adds the files to a mongoDB. The file upload returns the mongoDB id of the file (for example `12345`) and I want to add that id to the form as a hidden field so that the id is POSTed to the server upon submitting the form. Since the user can add multiple files though, I want to add a list of id's to the form.

I found how I can [add one hidden field to a form from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408098/1650012), but this always handles a single field, not a field with multiple values. So I thought of adding a checkbox field to the form so that I can submit multiple values in one element, but it kinda feels like a hack.

Can anybody hint me in the right direction on how I can add a hidden list of values to a form using Javascript? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
In the end I would like the form to look something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="[123, 534, 634, 938, 283, 293]">
    <input id="title" name="title" size="30" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Save this stuff">
</form>
```

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand what you mean by file-id? Or can you make a sample how the form should look with 2-3 items like you want it to be?

Comment: what is wrong with adding multiple hidden fields, one for each file?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow - Then what `name` do I give to the field? As far as I know every name should be unique. I could give them names like `file1` and `file2`, but then on the server side I have to iterate over all the possible names until I find the field is not present anymore. Isn't there a solution to provide a list with a form?

Comment: @Shaeldon - I added some clarification what I mean by id's. I store the files in mongodb and return an idea with the upload. I then want to add that id to a list of file-id's in the form. But I don't know how to add a hidden field containing a list of valuea, instead of just one value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, so I may just be guessing here.

Try adding multiple hidden inputs with a name such as **ids[]** so that they will be posted to the server as an array.

Example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="534">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="634">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="938">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="283">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="293">
    <input type="submit" value="Save this stuff">
</form>
```

Comment: Upvoted, this is the standard way of submitting multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that for each time the user clicks the 'upload' button you need to add a hidden field to the form?
Can you post the entire form, that should clear things up...

[Edit]
you could store the id's in an Array, everytime an id should be added to the hidden field's value you could do somthing like:
$('#ids').attr('value', idArray.join());

I'm just typing this out of the box so excuse any little errors

Comment: I added an example of how I would like the form to look in the end. Is there anything like this in forms?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply concatenating all the ids into a string like so "123,456,890,..etc" and then adding them as a value to ids inupt. When you need them, simply split by ',' which would give you an array with ids?

Todo so only with javascript something like this should work

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ids");
elem.value = elem.value + "," + newId;
```