# Inserting non-form data into database using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function in JavaScript with the following parameters below:

```
insertdata(micheal, newyork)
```

I want to be able to insert thus:

```
name = micheal
location = newyork
```

into my MySQL database using PHP and jQuery.

Both items of data are **not coming** from a form. I'm only passing them from JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Nutty. Your two questions thus far don't have a lot of detail, and this one may close as well as your other one, as it is rather broad. Please try to research questions before clicking the 'Ask Question' button. Additionally, if the answer below helped you, please consider accepting it with the tick mark. It seems you did so already, and then removed it - if you could explain to your helper why that is, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment due to reputation, I suggest you a solution that through jQuery you can append this to your current form as hidden fields and these get submitted at the PHP backend and you can save it in your DB.

Let me know if you need help on how to append it to the form.

```
var name = $("<input type='hidden' name='whatever' value='micheal' />");
$("#myform").append(name);
```

**Also have a look at this**

[Add elements using jQuery dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408043/jquery-create-hidden-form-element-on-the-fly)

To process this in PHP see this,

```
$variable_name_1 = $_POST['name_of_form_field_1'];
$variable_name_2 = $_POST['name_of_form_field_2'];

//Read how to sanitize variables
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2) VALUES ('$variable_name_1', '$variable_name_2')";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if(!$result) {
   echo "Error" . mysqli_error();
}
else {
  echo "Done!";
}
```

You can have a snapshot of your form submitted by doing this `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: i don't know how to append them to a form. please help. thanks

Comment: alright thanks. But how do i process these to the database. ;-(

Comment: Hey knight, i have appended both forms, how do i process from jquery -> to php. Thanks

Comment: var answer_chosen = $("<input type='hidden' name='answer_chosen' value='"+answer+"' />");
     
$("#myform").append(answer_chosen); I don't have a form per se. i just want the processing of this data to be from the jquery function